# Как навбар закинуть в main_view?

Tags: flutter

Имеются два **.dart** файла:

**main_view.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainView({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainView> createState() => _MainViewState();
}

class _MainViewState extends State<MainView>{

@override
...
return MaterialApp(
   home: Scaffold(
      ...
   ),
);
```

**bottom_nav_bar.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main_view.dart';

class BottomNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final MainView parent;

  const BottomNavBar({super.key, required this.parent});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Home'),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
          label: 'Profile'),
    ],
    );
  }
}
```

Как мне отобразить содержимое `BottomNavBar` в `MainView`, то есть отобразить навбар внизу?

Answer (score 0):

все, что тебе нужно - передать твой класс `BottomNavBar` в твой `Scaffold`.

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.asset('image'),
            Text('test')
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(),  //--------> this
    );
  }
}
```